# How can I protect users not to upload php scripts?

Tags: php, upload

How can I protect users not to upload php scripts ?

I put the below codes into .htaccess of ( /uploads/ ) folder.

```
<Files ^(*.php|*.phps)>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
<FilesMatch "\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|htm|shtml|sh|cgi.+)$">
ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

but i can still upload php files & php files are still executable. what's wrong with me or the codes ?

Comment: Are you worried about uploading files or just accessing them? Apache configs have nothing to do with your ability to upload a file.

Comment: Whitelist media files and then validate them with PHP.

Comment: check the file extension while uploading on server. nothing to do with `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

```
$allowed_ext = array("png","jpeg","gif");
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_ext = end(explode(".",$file_name));
if(in_array($file_ext,$allowed_ext)){
//uplod_here;
}
else{
//reject
}
```

Comment: *messi fan* thanks for the answer, what I'm searching is not the php solution. let say user(or)attacker could bypassed my /uploads/ folder and uploaded php script. but when they execute it, it won't do any action or it will be plain text. 
  ( sorry for my Eng )